# Optimize ByteTrack method in Multi Object Tracking

Tags: python, deep-learning, computer-vision

i'm doing some Multi Object Tracking project and using Bytetrack.

The point is that FPS of input video is pretty low and the object to track is small too, so that the number of ID switch is high when objects move fast.

I don't want to use tracking methods that require extract feature of object due to hardware limitations.
Can anyone suggest me a solution to this problem.

I'm following a way to adjust the Kalman Filter and ID switch is lower but haven't made it adapt in both cases that objects move fast and slow

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Adaptive Kalman FIlter?